# How to enable log4j for Marathon

Tags: log4j, marathon

I'd like to configure log4j for Marathon, where should I put the log4j.properties. I start Marathon by ./bin/start --master xxx

Comment: The marathon version is 0.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=file://path_of_log4j_properties
```